# Why can't I use a string uuid for a custom MongoDB _id in my NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, uuid, monk

I am developing a NodeJS app with a MongoDB database (using the native MongoDB NodeJS driver) and would like to use a string as my primary key.

This insertion fails for me when _id is a string:

```
   collection.insert({_id : "customId", name : "sampleName", email : "sampleEmail"}, {}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({msg : err});
        }
        else {
            res.send({msg : 'SUCCESS'});
        }
    });
```

This code is in my NodeJS app. When I try the same insertion through the mongo shell commands on my database, it works fine.

I know that custom _id fields for MongoDB primary keys must be guaranteed to be unique. I plan to use a uuid string in my code, but no string _id seems to work. I read here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names that _id must be unique and can be of any type except array. I have also reviewed this question [Creating custom Object ID in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211138/creating-custom-object-id-in-mongodb) which is similar, but it hasn't solved my issue. Why can't I use a string as a custom _id field?

Edit: The error message says "[Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters]"

Edit 2:

Here is my full code:

```
router.post('/addcontact', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;
var newContact = req.body;
var newContactId = uuid.v4();
var newContactId = String(newContactId);
//newContact['_id'] = newContactId;
var collection = db.get('contactlist');
console.log("about to do insert");
try {
    collection.insert({_id : '4BF6EFC6-1682-4A40-A0DE-8CD104AC92D3', name : "testName", email : "testEmail", phone : "testPhone"}, {}, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            res.send({msg : err});
        }
        else {
            res.send({msg : 'SUCCESS'});

            // log operation in log file with Kafka
            var producer = req.kafkaProducer;
            var payload = {topic : 'logging', messages: 'POST /addcontact id:' + newContactId + ' ' + newContact["name"]};
            producer.send([payload], function (err, data) {
            // console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
}
catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
} });
```

Note that I am not actually using the newContact info from the http POST, but just trying to get a sample insert to work.

Here is the console print out with the error:

```
about to do insert
[Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters]
POST /contacts/addcontact - - ms - -
```

Here is my package.json with dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "NodeApp2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "..",
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "couchbase": "^2.1.2",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "kafka-node": "..",
    "kerberos" : "..*",
    "mongodb": "2.0.49",
    "monk": "~1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node-gyp": "^3.1.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
```

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: The error says "[Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters]"

Comment: @zacdoe based on your comment, I think something is trying to case your `"customId"` to an `ObjectID`, which requires a 12 byte string.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I'm using the native mongodb driver. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: @zacdoe which version? The latest (2.0.49) doesn't care what you put in `_id`.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I just tried using a 12-byte string and it works fine. I'm still confused though, as I was under the belief that MongoDB's _id field didn't have this restriction.

Comment: @robertklep I was using 2.0.33. I'm trying to 2.0.49 now.

Comment: @zacdoe 2.0.33 works fine as well for me, [using this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/fe5d437ca7eeefb05238). As others have hinted, it sounds like something is trying to pass your id through `ObjectId()`.

Comment: @robertklep I'm getting the same error with 2.0.49.

Comment: @zacdoe I think you need to show more code, because that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're not actually using [`mongodb`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) directly, but through [`monk`](https://github.com/Automattic/monk) (`db.get('contactlist')` gave it away...), and `monk` automatically casts `_id` to `ObjectId`, which is why you're getting that error.

It looks like this behaviour [can't be turned off](https://github.com/Automattic/monk/issues/1), so you probably have to migrate your code to `mongodb`.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg perhaps monk users don't want to define their own `_id`'s? :-)

Comment: Yep, I'm not a fan of monk. It's too quirky.

Comment: @robertklep Every other Mongo driver (at least the ones I know of) support this though - if you don't specify an `_id` one will be provided for you

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I think that the latter (_"one will be provided for you"_) satisfies the majority of use-cases, which will work just fine with monk. It's only when you want to supply a non-ObjectId(-ish) `_id` that you will run into trouble there.

Answer (score 0):

`monk` does have an option to set uuid as your `_id` as per the [docs](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/insert.html). Simple set the `castIds` to false in the options object.

```
collection.insert(
    {_id: uuid, data: data},
    {castIds: false}
)
```