# How to save req.body object with a user ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save the request.body object containing an authenticated user ID into a new collection called useritems.

below is the req.body object with the user ID

```
{contact: "90000023", item: "Bread", price: "50", id: "5f4acf21287c6226ec0855af"}
```

next i find user with the id "5f4acf21287c6226ec0855af"

```
User.findOne({_id: _id}, function(err, items){

console.log(req.body)
    if (err) {
      console.log('err', err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      const newItem = new Item ({
        name:items.name,
        email:items.email,
        contact:req.body.contact,
        item:req.body.item,
        price:req.body.price,

      });
      newItem.save(function (err, item) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        res.send(item);
                    }
                });
      )
    }
})
})
```

here is the output:

```
{
   _id: 5f4e32006ce4d91a1cd811e2,// mongodb assigns new id. However, i still want the userID (5f4acf21287c6226ec0855af) persisted
   name: 'Bernad James',
   email: 'Ben@gmail.com',
   contact: 90000023,
   item: 'Bread',
   price: 50
}
```

how do I make it such that I am able to maintain the userID after save in the item collection

```
//here is my Item schema

const ItemSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  contact: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  item: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
```

And my user schema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
 password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
```

I want the userID persisted throughout so that i can always reference it to deal with particular authenticated logged in user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211138/creating-custom-object-id-in-mongodb#12211291](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211138/creating-custom-object-id-in-mongodb#12211291)